# How to create a bug bounty?

Tags: bugs

I'm trying to create a bug bounty with bountysource but there isn't any specific option that assures me the money is redirected to that bug. What are the correct steps to create a bug bounty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elementary OS has [ended their relationship](https://blog.elementary.io/goodbye-bountysource-hello-github-sponsors/) with Bountysource